# svcutil.exe does not handle ws-policy

Tags: .net, web-services, sap-pi

Svcutil.exe gives this warning:

> The optional WSDL extension element 'Policy' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy' was not handled.

and a team member reports a similar Java tool crashes with an exception (I don't have any details).

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:p1="urn:mycompany.com:fi:myservice" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" name="MyService" targetNamespace="urn:mycompany.com:fi:myservice">
   <wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true" />
   <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP_DoSomething" />
   <wsdl:portType name="MyPort">
      <wsdl:operation name="DoSomething">
         <wsp:Policy>
            <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP_DoSomething" />
         </wsp:Policy>
         <wsdl:input message="p1:MyRequest" />
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Removing the policy elements solves the problem. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is this from a WSE service? That may not be the namespace for the current version of the standard.

Comment: This is from an SAP PI web service

Comment: Perhaps you could look at the SAP documentation - there may be options as far as how to generate the SAP WSDL. Maybe 1.2 is the default.

Comment: Not sure if there's been a solution to this since 2013, but since this element is optional it seems you can safely ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of WS-Policy is version 1.5. It uses the namespace `http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy`.

See "[XML Namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-policy-primer/#xml-namespaces)".

---

Indeed, it looks like you've got version 1.2. It uses `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/ws-policy.xsd`. See http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/.

Comment: Thanks John. However, svcutil outputs the same warning with the new namespace.